# NET Core 6.0 : Is possible to create generic methods to get a List<T> from EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have the following methods to take from 5 different views a list of said view from EF Core 6.0 :

```
    public List<Vw_Customers> GetCustomers(THEDBContext dbContext)
    {
        return dbContext.Vw_Customers.ToList();
    }

    public List<VW_Cars> GetCars(THEDBContext dbContext)
    {
        return dbContext.VW_Cars.ToList();
    }
```

and so on...

It works, but I have to make "n" methods to take data from my database.

Is there a way where I can get the specific List passing the class of the view, like

```
    public List<dynamic> GetData(THEDBContext dbContext, Class myViewClass)
    {
        return dbContext.myViewClass.ToList();
    }
```

?

Searching around StackOverflow I found to use `dbContext.Set<MyClass>` but it doesn't work with latest EF Core version.

Comment: `dbContext.Set<T>().ToList()` is the generic way. `List<dynamic> GetData(THEDBContext dbContext, Class myViewClass)` is not generic at all. And the purpose of `Class` argument is unclear.

Comment: EF Core methods are already generic. The code you posted is already generic.

Comment: You do realize that these methods download the entire table out of the datable and load it into C# when they're used? They're nearly the most ineffective use of your database possible. You might as well keep your data in CSV files. THe whole idea of EF is that it can see you do `dbContext.Customers.Where(...).GroupBy(...).Select(...)` and translate that to SQL, so you quickly download a minimal set of data, grouping millions of rows into a handful, quicker network transit time, getting the DB to do what its best at..

Comment: A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work for specific *entities*, it's not a database connection or a full database model. The DbSet classes are repositories for specific entities - whether you use `DbSet<T>` properties or `Set<T>()` you still have to configure those entities. Naming your entities `vw_Something` suggest you're using DbContext as if it was a SqlConnection

Comment: *Searching around StackOverflow I found to use dbContext.Set* - but it doesn't make sense, because you'll do e.g. `var allCust = dbContext.Set<Customer>().ToList()` * - that's more typing than just doing `var allCust = dbContext.Customers.ToList()` ... *(or similar with your new method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
public  class MyClass<T> where T : class
{
    public List<T> GetData(THEDBContext dbContext)
    {
       return dbContext.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

 }
```

This is the generic way to return data from dbcontext, I assume you use 'dynamic' word to describe it will be something not fixed. Otherwise if you want to use [dynamic type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)  It is not genereic at all and I don't recomend it you to use in this case.

You should look some documentations and  [tutorials](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/generic-repository-pattern-csharp-mvc/) in order to understand how [generic classes and methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) works.

Comment: That's nothing more than an aliased call to `ToList()`, which is already generic. It's *more* verbose than what the OP is already using for no benefit. You can't use `Set<T>()` without first configuring that entity. The DbSet<> properties are little different than `Set<>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not exatcly this way but with an abstract base class and interface I use like this to use generic repository pattern. Do you use any more efficient way ?If so, I would like to see.

Comment: "generic repository" is an *anti*pattern when used on top of EF Core. A DbSet is already a single-entity generic repository. A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work.  These already track changes, already manage connections, already persist all changes in a single transaction. `any more efficient way` yes, just don't try to generalize the already generic classes and methods.

Comment: When you have an ORM implementing the generic repo and UoW, what you need is *specialized* repositories for the specific use case/bounded context you use them in. After all, the ORM already abstracts the actual storage to a large number of databases. If you had to switch from a relational database (set-based) to a document database (item based) like Mongo the changes would be so great your "generic repository" would break and only the high-level *specialized* repositories could be reused

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I disagree. Generic repository pattern with centerelized context is quite helpful in order to help DRY and cut some development time. You can have specilized repositories which derived from generic base repository and use both for different cases. Also submitting changes over one context isn't better than calling multiple context ?Beside all this question isn't about what you point. The user seems to be confused about how to use generics with context.  My answer I believe help this.

Comment: No, this doesn't help with generics, it shows additional confusion about both generics and EF Core. `ToList<T>()` is already generic. The DbSet properties are just placeholders. You need to read Gunnar Peipman's [No Need for Repository and Unit of Work with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) to see just how broken a "generic repository" over an already generic repository is. If you have an `Insert` method that calls `SaveChanges`, you're persisting all pending changes. That `Insert` could result in 42 DELETEs and 67 UPDATEs.

Comment: As for specialization, you misunderstood what I said. I don't mean *derived*, I mean repositories built to handle a specific *use case*. The generic case is already handled by DbContext-derived classes. A reporting use case needs different methods and has different data access patterns from a data entry use case.

Comment: None of this is new by the way, [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) was written in 2009. By one of the people that actually helped create the ORMs and patterns we use today.